# Using a logical operator in an ngClass condition with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I want to apply some styles when a batch status is not `in progress` or not `done`.

I wrote:

```
<td ng-class="{'paddingLeft' : item.status !== 'in progress' || item.status !== 'done'}">
```

This did not work.

But when I do them individually:

```
<td ng-class="{'paddingLeft' : item.status !== 'in progress'}">
```

or

```
<td ng-class="{'paddingLeft' : item.status !== 'done'}">
```

That works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`item.status !== 'in progress' || item.status !== 'done'` this condition is **always `true`**.

I think it should be:

```
item.status !== 'in progress' && item.status !== 'done'
```